# java multithreading suspend(); resume(); threads

Tags: java, multithreading

The question is to write a java program which include a class MyThread.The class uses
     thread to display numbers from 1 to 10.  Suspend thread one and
     resume  after 10000 millisecond;

```
import java.lang.*;

class Mythread extends Thread
{
 public void run(){
     for(int x =1;x<=10;x++){

         System.out.println(x);
     }
     suspend();
      resume();


 }
}
class a{
    public static void main (String[] args){
    Mythread q = new Mythread();
    q.start();
}
}
```

This code is not working!  suspend(); resume(); how these two threads put in this code?

Comment: That's not a question.  It looks more like a do-my-homework-for-me kind of thing.

Comment: If you're suspending a `Thread` for a certain amount of time, I'd looking into `Thread#sleep`.

Comment: Note, that `suspend()` and `resume()` are deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: i need to learn more about thread programing, any link or web site do you know? plz tell me!

Comment: @john just google "java concurrency". Asking for off-site content, like tutorials, is off-topic for stackoverflow as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: thanks for your advice!

Answer (score -1):

Use `Thread.sleep()` then put however many milliseconds you want inside the parenthesis. This will stop executing code, then continue after 10,000 milliseconds.

You said you wanted 10000 so it would look something like `Thread.sleep(10000)`